# No pharaohs here, move along

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, geography

> A bowl can hold my start in place,
>   But try not catch one with your face.
>   No continent do I embrace;
>   You may think "pharaohs" – not the case.
>
> A Dutchman caught me in his sight,
>   But no one thought that could be right.
>   A white-head giant of some might,
>   Of my own kind none match my height.

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are

> the Carstensz Pyramid (or Puncak Jaya), which is the highest summit of Mount Carstensz in Indonesia

A bowl can hold my start in place,
But try not catch one with your face.

> The usual route to climb this member of the "Seven Summits" is near Grasberg mine, a large bowl shaped mine on one of the faces of the mountain.  Also, the name Puncak Jaya sounds like punch, which you don't want to catch in your face (as pointed out by @Tom)

No continent do I embrace;

> Being on an island it is in Oceania, but not true Australia or Asia

You may think "pharaohs" – not the case.

> the name has pyramid in it, but not the Egyptian kind

A Dutchman caught me in his sight,
But no one thought that could be right.

> In 1623, Dutch explorer Jan Carstensz spotted the snow/glacier topped mountain, but was ridiculed when he returned to Europe because they did not believe snow capped mountains could exist that near the equator

A white-head giant of some might,
Of my own kind none match my height.

> It is snow capped (though the glacier has long since melted).  And it is the tallest mountain in Oceania and the tallest island mountain in the world.

Comment: Great! The name used for the first two lines may be [rot13](https://www.rot13.com/) Chapnx Wnln fbhaqvat yvxr chapu.

Comment: This is correct. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be:

> Mount Everest

No continent do I embrace

> It's between 2 tectonic plates

A white-head giant of some might

> It's peak is covered in snow

Of my own kind none match my height.

> It's the highest mountain in the world

(Not sure about the other clues yet)

Comment: I like the answer!  but I thought rot13(Rirerfg jnf pbzcyrgryl va Nfvn?)

Comment: @SteveV rot13(V'z abg gnyxvat nobhg gur pbagvarag. Vg'f orgjrra gur Vaqvna naq Rhenfvna grpgbavp cyngrf.)

Comment: Well, regarding the last line, that is only true if you are considering mountains with a base *above* sea level (just to be technical) :P